# The use of "follow through"

Tags: grammaticality

I was making preps for a coming exam and this suddenly came to me:

Can I say "I am that kind of person who always follows through once I make a promise"?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds slightly more natural in my opinon to say "I am *the* kind of person..." but otherwise yes, that's a very normal sentence.

Comment: Yes, but "correct my usage" is not really what we do here.

Answer (score 0):

When I search about follow through, then I decide the following :

I am that kind of person who always follows through **on** promise once made.

Further, *both that and the are possible* :

Then again, no one has the kind
of expertise held by John.

Only a handful of students have that kind of motivation.

Comment: I agree with you regarding “that/the kind of person” *in general* but in *this sentence* only “the” works grammatically. Your version of the sentence has another significant error. Do you mean, “...on promises once made.”? Finally, have I missed something in the reference to “Park”? (Don’t tell me you mean the former South Korean President!)

Comment: Thank you for your correction in use 'once'. For the second, I do not know well what you are talking about.